# Why does an antiderivative of real function $f$ need to be defined on a closed interval?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

\begin{align}
\ F:\mathbb{R}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{R}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\ f:\mathbb{R}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{R}
\end{align}

Why does $F$, which is an antiderivative of $f$ ($f$ is continuous on interval $(a..b)$) need to be continous on closed interval $[a..b]$ and not just on $(a..b)$ too? [Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Primitive_(Calculus)/Real) is my source.

Comment: The proofwiki page is badly phrased. $F$ is only a primitive of $f$ on the common domain. $F$ may be defined on a larger domain than $f$ (or on a smaller domain, or on a domain that is neither contained in the domain of $f$ nor contains it), but it's only a primitive of $f$ where both are defined and the equality $F' = f$ holds.

Comment: @hardmath "Primitive" is the traditional term. The ugly un-word "antiderivative" is a recent invention.

Comment: @hardmath No objection to having questions as self-contained as possible. On the other hand, defining every used term in every question would soon become unwieldy. The purpose of the link to proofwiki was not to define the term primitive - which the OP probably expected to be known; alas it is no more - but to show where the OP got the notion that a primitive has to be defined on a closed interval (since the page says "Let $F$ … on the closed interval $[a,b]$ …").

Comment: I upvoted since the meaning is clarified. I think this sort of misunderstanding is a good use of the site and would like to see your comment posted as an answer, i.e. it's a matter of definition and the reason we define the functions to have a common domain is basically a convenience.  However $F$ is "smoother" than $f$, so will typically be continuous on a larger domain when there's a difference.